# Problems compiling pshtoolkit

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have downloaded the pass the hash toolkit source codes from [here](http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pshtoolkit.htm). When I am compiling it with Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, I would get the following error:

```
findfuncs_msv10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetModuleInformation@16 referenced in function _FindMSV10Functions
whosthere-alt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LsaFreeReturnBuffer@4 referenced in function _GetLogonSessionData
whosthere-alt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LsaGetlogonSessionData@8 referenced in function _GetLogonSessionData
whosthere-alt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LsaEnumerateLogonSession@8 referenced in function _main
```

How do I solve this error or is there another better way to compile the code. I'm new to C and I'm open to any suggestions.

Update: I have linked the Secur32.lib and the Psapi.lib and it compiles. Thanks alot

Comment: You need to include the library which implements GetModuleInformation()

Comment: You downloaded it from here? where's that?

Comment: It was a typo error, I got it at http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pshtoolkit.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to link to some additional libraries.

If you search for the functions listed in the errors (minus the leading underscore) in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/), it'll show you which libraries to link to.

e.g.

- [GetModuleInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is in either Kernel32.lib or Psaip.lib, depending on the version of Windows you're using
- [LsaGetLogonSessionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is in Secur32.lib

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *.lib files to the Visual Studio project.

[image: Example]